# How to make a button appear in condition in Odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I create a module that inherit module stock.inventory,
I want the button "1st validate" only appears when "real quantity" is different from "theoretical quantity".
Here is the inteface:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkNQB.png)

Here is my xml code:

```
    <record id="linh_view_inventory_form_ext" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">linh.view.inventory.form.ext</field>
            <field name="model">stock.inventory</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock_account.view_inventory_form_inherit"/>
            <field name="form">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">

                 <button name="action_cancel_inventory" states="confirm" string="Cancel Inventory" type="object" position="before">     
                    <button name="inventory_1st_validate" states="need_validate" string="1st Validate" class="oe_highlight" type="object" attrs="{'invisible':[('theoretical_qty','=','product_qty')]}/>           
                 </button>

                <field name="state" position="replace">
                    <field name="state" widget="statusbar" statusbar_visible="draft,confirm,acct_validated,done"/>              
                </field>
            </field>
    </record>
```

But I got this error:

> Error: Unknown field theoretical_qty in domain
>   [["theoretical_qty","=","product_qty"],["state","not
>   in",["need_validate"]]]

"theoretical_qty" is the field name of "theoretical quantity" which I got from model "stock.picking". I don't know why the view doesn't recognize it.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: This may be a dependence problem, check if the __openerp__.py files has the module that creates that field in the "depends" attr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`theoretical_qty` is the field of **stock.inventory.line** you can't use  directly inside **stock.inventory** .

you can use it in tree/form view of stock.inventory.line only.

One more thing , for using a field inside attrs it **must** be present on view also .

(either in the current view or inherited parent view ).